# How do I avoid this ImageMagick anti-aliasing discoloration?

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, transparent, alpha, antialiasing

## Update:

Thanks to a suggestion from paddy, it has come to my attention that the anti-aliasing looks fine on one of my machines, but not the other.

---

I'm trying to create a 24x24 png that features a filled shape with a transparent background. Here is the command I am working with:

```
convert -size 24x24 xc:none \
        -fill red \
        -draw "path 'M 0,0 L 24,0 A 24,24 0 0,0 0,24 Z' " result.png
```

> "xc: _____" specifies a background color. (maybe this is where I'm mistaken?)

The output gives me the correct shape, but the border between the shape and the transparent area (i.e. the anti-aliased edge between color and transparency) is noticeably darkened:

[image: ImageMagick expected vs. result]

The anti-aliasing shown on the right is what I want from ImageMagick. Here's what I get for different values of xc:

[image: Different ImageMagick xc values]

As you can see, the anti-aliasing blends fine with solid colors, but not with transparency. The ImageMagick guide has [a section on anti-aliasing](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/antialiasing/) and the problems it can cause, but reading through it, none of it's examples cover transparency. Any ideas?

Comment: What version are you using?  `convert --version`.  I'm guessing by your screenshots that you're using this on Mac OS X.  I also have ImageMagick on Mac OS X, installed with [Brew](http://brew.sh).  My version is reported as `ImageMagick 6.9.0-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-03-08`, and the transparent antialiasing looks fine.

Comment: I'm running convert version 6.9.1-2 Q16 i686 2015-04-22 on Crunchbang 11 Waldorf. However, I have it installed on my OSX machine too (6.9.1-6 Q16 x86_64 2015-06-22), and you're absolutely right, it looks fine. So, it's definitely something wrong with my Crunchbang box/installation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to a more recent version of ImageMagick/convert (6.9.1-6 Q16 i686 2015-06-30) fixed the problem for me. (Thanks, paddy)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `-background Red -alpha Background`? I suspect that the background color is defaulting to black, which is then being blurred with the red against the transparent background.

Comment: That *is* what it looks like, doesn't it. I tried this: `convert -size 24x24 xc: -background red -alpha background -fill blue -draw "path 'M 0,0  L 24,0 A 24,24 0 0,0 0,24 Z' " triangle_curved.png` but it removed the transparency and gave it a white background.

Answer (score 0):

Try `xc:transparent` over `xc:none`

```
convert -size 24x24 xc:transparent \
    -fill red \
    -draw "path 'M 0,0 L 24,0 A 24,24 0 0,0 0,24 Z' " result.png
```

As @paddy pointed out in the comments, this issue was resolved in later versions of IM

Comment: xc:transparent does not fix it for me with this version of IM. *shrug*

Comment: @DustinPaluch Ah! this is not the issue I'm thinking of, but with the SVG delegates between systems. There is a way to enforce vector graphics to use MVG over RSVG library. I'll update my answer if I can dig-up the docs.